# Creating colored .obj file (point cloud with color)

Tags: colors, .obj, meshlab

I have all-focus image and depth-map image. Using depth map image I can create .obj file(point cloud). But in meshlab I can see only points without color. How can I add color information for .obj file?

(could you show me simple example of .obj file with color info)....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is not related to meshlab, and seems you did a poor research effort before of bring it here. Anyway, here you have a .obj file with color info, just add values of R, G, B after the coordinates.

```
v 1220.094482 -572.500000 77.713943 1.0 0.0 0.0  
v 1291.571533 -609.439636 28.628490 0.0 1.0 0.0
v 1251.571533 -609.439636 38.628490 1.0 1.0 1.0    
f 1 2 3
```